# Extract text from a web page and show it in textview on ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, cocoa, webkit

Imagine a web page on internet,that this web page consist of menus,text,… how can i extract just text and show it in a textview on ios?

Is it possible to do that ?if yes am i need learning web services ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible and basically there are 2 options for you.

- If you are talking about a site which is not your own and doesnt have a web service that you can access.You either need to write a crawler for the site to extract what content you want.And then publish it to your iOS client either with your own web service or directly through a socket etc.
- If the data or the site is your own and in your control just publish it through a web service.

Comment: That way is called Website scraping try googling it there are tons of options,frameworks etc.E.g for a nice tutorial for php : http://www.codediesel.com/php/web-scraping-in-php-tutorial/